# Slow return from sleep

Tags: suspend, lenovo, 19.10, iwlwifi

I am trying to debug my suspend/hibernate issues on my laptop. Starting with suspend.

Suspend is successful, but waking lands me at a black screen with kernel text for about 45 seconds before bringing me back to desktop. Timeline is detailed below, followed by the message shown from the kernel followed by full syslog of the timeframe.

I have tried:

- to disable the wifi adapter in Windows as I had read that might clear up the iwlwifi issue but it did not.
- blacklist ucsi_ccg in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and it got rid of the mssage and replaced it with:

`usb usb6-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?`

- to remove all USB devices

Further if anyone can predict what kind of issues might cause a failure to hibernate before I get there that would be helpful!

- OS: Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64 (Dual-boot configuration with Windows 10)
- Kernel: 5.3.0-42-generic
- Laptop: Lenovo Y740
- 8 GB swap file, 16 GB physical memory

Timeline for sleeping/waking:

- 15:08:30 pressed suspend button (+0:00)
- 15:09:00 pressed wake button (+0:30)
- 15:09:45 black screen stopped (+1:15)
- 15:09:47 back to desktop (+1:17)

The black screen says the following:

```
Mar 18 15:09:42 arc kernel: [ 1088.043584] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
Mar 18 15:09:41 arc kernel: [ 1086.955122] PM: dpm_run_callback(): ucsi_ccg_resume+0x0/0x20 [ucsi_ccg] returns -110
Mar 18 15:09:41 arc kernel: [ 1086.955126] PM: Device 0-0008 failed to resume: error -110
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug in kernel 5.3 with nvidia's ucsi_ccg module.

blacklist ucsi_ccg in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf actually did fix the delay. I still get the iwlwifi error but that doesn't hold it up for as long.

I had a typo in my blacklist.conf and that's why it didn't work before.